# label databinding not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am DataBinding to a readonly property to the Text property of a Label in Windows Forms.

```
lblSourceLoggingState.DataBindings.Add("Text", machine, "Status");
```

My problem with this is the text only gets updated at startup of the form.
I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a base class like this:

```
    protected void SetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property, T value)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = property;

        if (lambdaExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Lambda expression return value can't be null", "property");
        }

        string propertyName = PropertyName.GetMemberName(lambdaExpression);

        T storedValue = getValue<T>(propertyName);

        if (Equals(storedValue, value))
            return;

        _propertyValueStorage[propertyName] = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}

public SynchronizationContext SyncContext;
protected ViewModelBase()
{
    SyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    _propertyValueStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}


protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        if (SyncContext != null)
            SyncContext.Send(obj => handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        else
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And here the Code in the machine object for Status Property:

```
    public short Status
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => Status); }
        private set { SetValue(() => Status, value); }
    }
```

While debugging and stepping through the SetValue or OnPropertyChanged methods the Label text gets updated, but if i run the application without breakpoints it wont.
Also if i register to the PropertyChangedEvent like this:

```
        machine.PropertyChanged += delegate(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == "Status")
                lblSourceLoggingState.Text = machine.Status.ToString();
        };
```

the label text also gets updated like it should so what could go wrong with the DataBindings?